# SQL Server Map multiple columns in Case When Then

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I don't want to repeat my solution 1 for each column, but rather what i want is that i should have only one condition and i should be able to set different values in different column on the basis of that.

Normally in an SQL Select statement we can do this.

**Solution 1:**

```
select
  abc  as column1,
  def  as column2,
  (
     case
     when someColumn is not null
        then (1)
     else 0
 end
 ) as column3
```

But what i want to do is that if some condition is met such as (someColumn is not null), then set 1 to column3, set 2 to coulmn 4 e.t.c
How can i do that. I want to achieve something like this.

**What is required:**

```
SELECT
     (
      case
      when column is null   
      then( 
               1 as column3,
               2 as column4
         )
      else  (
               10 as column3,
               20 as column4
        )
     ))
from table.
```

Regards.

Comment: What if you use an `IF`?

Comment: No, A CASE expression returns a single value, you cant use it like a control of flow construct.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using `CASE`, but it's so easy using **[IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)**:

```
DECLARE @Test INT = NULL;

--NULL case
SELECT IIF(@Test IS NULL, 1, 10) AS Col3, IIF(@Test IS NULL, 2, 20) AS Col4;

SET @Test = 1;
--NOT NULL case
SELECT IIF(@Test IS NULL, 1, 10) AS Col3, IIF(@Test IS NULL, 2, 20) AS Col4;
```

Results (NULL):

```
+------+------+
| Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
```

Results (NOT NULL):

```
+------+------+
| Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+
|   10 |   20 |
+------+------+
```

Here is a simple **[demo](http://rextester.com/VFL39358)**.

Update:

Here is how you can use an `IIF` inside `IIF` to solve your issue

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    TestCol INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(NULL),
(1),
(2),
(3),
(NULL),
(1),
(2),
(55);
SELECT *, 
       IIF(TestCol IS NULL, 1, IIF(TestCol = 1, 11, IIF(TestCol = 2, 22 , IIF(TestCol = 3 , 33 , 0)))) AS Col3, 
       IIF(TestCol IS NULL, 11, IIF(TestCol = 1, 111, IIF(TestCol = 2, 222 , IIF(TestCol = 3 , 333 , 100)))) AS Col4
FROM MyTable;
```

See the **[demo](http://rextester.com/ZIAW92041)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is still there. I still have repeat my condition (column is null or some other condition like that) number of times. This is what i donot like to use.

Comment: @UmairKhalid You can use `IIF` inside `IIF` like `IIF( Col IS NULL, 1 , IFF(1, 2 ,3) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Driven approach. Add all case values in @CaseTable table and join it with main table. and get values from Case table

```
DECLARE @CaseTable TABLE (CaseValue INT, column3 INT, column4 INT)
INSERT INTO @CaseTable VALUES 
(1, 1, 2), 
(2,10,20)

DECLARE @TheTable  TABLE (column1 VARCHAR(10), column2 VARCHAR(10), someColumn VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TheTable VALUES
('abc','def', 'xyx'),
('ghi','jkl', NULL)

SELECT column1, column2, C.column3, C.column4 FROM @TheTable T
LEFT JOIN @CaseTable C ON C.CaseValue = (CASE WHEN T.someColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` for this type of need ([demo](http://rextester.com/UDHLT66130))

```
SELECT CA.column3,
       CA.column4
FROM   YourTable t
       /*conditions are mutually exclusive and guaranteed that one is true
         so will output one row per outer row*/
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT 1, 2 WHERE  column0 IS NULL
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10, 20 WHERE  column0 IS NOT NULL
                   )CA(column3, column4)
```